# Camel JPA @Consumed alternatives

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel

My main question is : **Is there any alternative to @Consumed annotation on a method inside the JPA entity class ?**

I ask this question because I really want to externalize my JPA model (eg. all my entities) to be able to share among onther projects using the same database. Also I don't want some Camel dependancies in my sub-project that implies to delete the @Consumed annotation.
I basically have a route like this :

```
from("jpa://[MyClass]?consumeLockEntity=true&consumer.SkipLockedEntity=true&consumer.query=[...]")
    .to("seda:queue.test")
```

I tried different solutions :

- Extend the sub-module camel free entity class in my camel-project with an @Consumed method. But JPA does not allow inheritance without a discriminant field...
- Add a bean/processor at the end of my Camel route to manually update the entity state. But my route ends in a dead lock (as expected).

Is there other solution I forgot ? Is there (in the route configuration) some place to put "route ending method" ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution should work. I think your route ends up with a dead lock because your Bean tries to update your entity whereas you are already in a transaction.
If that's the case, removing your update in your Bean should work.

Still your first sollution is worthsome. If someone tried it, I am interested to know if it worked.